# How does Function.prototype.call.bind work?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am having some trouble wrapping my head around this function:

```
var toStr = Function.prototype.call.bind( Object.prototype.toString );
toStr([]) // [object Array]​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

How does this function accept an argument as seen in line 2?

Comment: _"How does this work?"_ Can you be more specific please?

Comment: [Read this documentation about bind() in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Well,

- `Function.prototype.call` references the "call" function, which is used to invoke functions with chosen `this` values;
- The subsequent `.bind` refers to the "bind" function on the Function prototype (remember: "call" is a function too), which returns a new function that will always have `this` set to the passed-in argument.
- The argument passed to "bind" is the "toString" function on the Object prototype, so the result of that whole expression is a new function that will run the "call" function with `this` set to the "toString" function.

The result, therefore, is like this code: `Object.prototype.toString.call( param )`. Then, the "console.log" call passes that function an array, and there you have it.

*edit* Note that `Object.prototype.toString.call( param )` is like `param.toString()` really, when "param" is an object. When it's not, then the semantics of the "call" function are to turn it into one in the normal ways JavaScript does that (numbers -> Number, strings -> String, etc).

*edit, 24 May2016* — That last sentence above is not accurate with ES2015. New JavaScript runtimes do *not* "autobox" primitive types when those are involved with a function call as a `this` value.

Answer (score 10):

I assume you already know what `.call` and `.bind` do

`toStr` is now a function that essentially does:

```
function toStr( obj ) {
    return Function.prototype.call.call( Object.prototype.toString, obj );
}
```

I.E it `.call`s the `.call` function with context argument set to the `.toString` function. Normally that part is already taken care of because you normally use `.call` as a property of some function which sets the function as the context for the `.call`.

Answer (score 3):

The two lines of code are a function definition and then execution call of that definition with an empty array passed inside. The complexity lies in interpreting what 'this' will point to and why.

To help deduce the value of this I copied content from two links below to MDN's definitions of call and bind.

The [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)() function creates a new function (a bound function) with the same function body as the function it is being called on (the bound function's target function) with the this value bound to the first argument of bind(). Your code looks similar to a 'shortcut function' described on the bind page.

```
var unboundSlice = Array.prototype.slice; // same as "slice" in the previous example
var slice = Function.prototype.call.bind(unboundSlice);
```

// ...

slice(arguments);

> With [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), you can assign a different this object when calling an
>   existing function. this refers to the current object, the calling
>   object.With call, you can write a method once and then inherit it in
>   another object, without having to rewrite the method for the new
>   object.

When toStr is called it passes in an array to bind, of which the this pointer is bound.
With bind(), this can be simplified.

`toStr() is a bound function to the call() function of Function.prototype, with the this value set to the toStr() function of Array.prototype. This means that additional call() calls can be eliminated`.

In essence, it looks like a shortcut function override to the toString method.

Answer (score 2):

**bind()** - Creates a new function that, when called, itself calls this function in the context of the provided this value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function was called.

[Read this documentation for more information about bind() in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Angular example:

Parent component where we have a defined function and bind it to an object:

```
public callback: object;

constructor() {
    this.callback= this.myFunction.bind(this);
}

public myFunction($event: any) {
    // Do something with $event ...
}
```

(Parent html) passing the binded object to child component:

```
<child-component (callbackFunction)="callback($event)"></child-component>
```

Child component that receives the object that is bind to the parent function:

```
@Output() callbackFunction: EventEmitter<object> = new EventEmitter<object>();

public childFunction() {
    ...
    this.callbackFunction.emit({ message: 'Hello!' });
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**JS to English translation -**

> var toStr = Function.prototype.call.bind( Object.prototype.toString );

The `bind` creates a new `call` function of `Object.prototype.toString`.

Now you can call this new function with any context which will just be applied to `Object.prototype.toString`.

Like this:

```
toStr([]) // [object Array]​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

---

Why not just calling `Object.prototype.toString.call([])` ??

**Answer:**

Of course, you could. But the OPs method creates a dedicated and de-methodized function just for this purpose.

This really is called demethodizing.

Answer (score 1):

You could do :

```
var toStr = Object.prototype.toString.call([]);
```

**Problem with this is** : call executes instantly.
What you want is to delay the execution of call.

*As function is an object too in Javascript, you can use any function as the first argument in '*call*' instead of passing an object as 1st argument.*Also, you can use the dot on call like on any object.

**Function.prototype.call.bind( Object.prototype.toString )** , makes a copy of the call function with it's '**this**' sets to *Object.prototype.toString* .
You hold this new copy of call function in 'toStr'.

```
var toStr = Function.prototype.call.bind( Object.prototype.toString );
```

Now you can executes this new copy of call any time you need without the need of setting 'this' as it's 'this' is already bind to Object.prototype.toString .

Answer (score 1):

1. This should make sense to you

```js
Object.prototype.toString.call([]) // work well
```

2. You think this form is too long and cumbersome and you want to simplify it? This makes it easier to use later:

```js
const toStr = Object.prototype.toString.call
toStr([]) // unfortunately, this does not work
```

3. You need to use `bind` to correct where `this` points to.

```js
const toStr = Object.prototype.toString.call.bind(Object.prototype.toString)
toStr([]) // work well
```

4. `Object.prototype.toString.call` is just the same as `Function.prototype.call`

```js
const toStr = Function.prototype.call.bind(Object.prototype.toString)
toStr([]) // done
```

5. `Function` is also a function, so `Function.call` refers exactly to `Function.prototype.call`

```js
const toStr = Function.call.bind(Object.prototype.toString) // even simpler
toStr([]) // done
```

**summary**

`f.call` is just the same as `Function.call.bind(f)`

`f.call(1,2,3)` is just the same as `Function.call.bind(f,1)(2,3)`